# How is data-type argument used in the Value function of TensorFlow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

While creating variables in TensorFlow we can specify the data type. However, it looks to me that this argument is just ignored. For example:

```
In [26]: b = tf.Variable([3.0, 4.0, 5.0], tf.float64)

In [27]: b.dtype
Out[27]: tf.float32_ref

In [28]: b = tf.Variable(np.array([3.0, 4.0, 5.0]), tf.float64)

In [29]: b.dtype
Out[29]: tf.float64_ref

In [30]: b = tf.Variable(np.array([3.0, 4.0, 5.0]), tf.float32)

In [31]: b.dtype
Out[31]: tf.float64_ref
```

So, if I initialize values from a Python list, I get `tf.float32_ref` as the type (even though I give `tf.float64` as the second argument of the `Value` function). If I use a numpy array for the value initialization, the situation is opposite (I get `tf.float64_ref` as the data type even if I give `tf.float32` as the second argument of the `Value` function).

I guess that the data-type is taken from the data-type of the object that is used for the value initialization. Which kind of makes sense, but than why do we need the dtype argument in the `Value` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is just that the 2nd argument of Variable constructor is not dtype:

```
>>>b = tf.Variable(np.array([3.0, 4.0, 5.0]), tf.float32)
>>>b.dtype
tf.float64_ref
>>>b = tf.Variable(np.array([3.0, 4.0, 5.0]), dtype=tf.float32)
>>>b.dtype
tf.float32_ref
```

You can check the doc [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable): the 2nd argument is "trainable".

As a side note: in more recent versions of Tensorflow, it is [advised](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables) to use `tf.get_variable` to create variables instead of `tf.Variable()`.

Comment: Second argument is name of the variable, not trainable parameter.

Comment: I don't understand... In `__init__()` function of the doc, I see `__init__(
    initial_value=None,
    trainable=True,
    collections=None,
    validate_shape=True,
    caching_device=None,
    name=None,
    variable_def=None,
    dtype=None,
    expected_shape=None,
    import_scope=None
)`

Comment: Anyway the consclusion is the same: one should use named parameters